# Increase node heap memory size in azure httptrigger function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-http-trigger

I'm creating serverless httptrigger function in azure. And then I execute the function by http get call.

My function executes just fine. But if during runtime there is too many data loaded then I get `JavaScript heap out of memory` error.

In my local env if I get the issue I can increase the heap size by the command

`NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096`

But how I can do the same in the azure environment?
Is there any way to connect the azure environment by command line?
Or in the azure UI do we have any option to set up the heap size for azure env?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> I get `JavaScript heap out of memory` error.

#### To avoid the issue, follow the below step:

Add `languageWorkers:node:arguments` in environment variables.
In the **Azure Portal > Function App > Configuration > Application Settings > New Application Setting**

> As @[empz](https://github.com/empz) mentioned in GitHub -> add the app setting `languageWorkers:node:arguments` (use `languageWorkers__node__arguments` for Linux function apps) with a value of `--max-old-space-size=<max memory in MB>`

[image]

Refer to the GitHub Az Function Node Heap Memory Issue [68614](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/68614#issuecomment-760789826) for more information.